# maxWidth for infowindow in googlemaps?

Tags: google-maps

The part of my google maps code that creates info windows is this:

```
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

I need to set a max width of 250px to the infowindow but I cant get it to work. Is there a syntax error with the following:

```
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.maxWidth(250);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

Comment: The InfoWindow class hasn't got any `maxWidth` method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working:

```
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    // where I have added .html to the marker object.
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth:250}); 
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

Comment: It works on desktop. Not on Mobile (android at least).

Comment: I was struggling to add maxWidth and this specific line, 'infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth:250}); ' really helped. Thank you.